# How do I create a border around a rectangle in an image(PIX) in Leptonica?

Tags: c++, c, image, leptonica

I have an image in PIX format, and I have a BOX[with the necessary coordinates] too, I would like to draw a border around the content that's in the box, like for example -
[image: example]

I've looked around in the documentation, but so far I've only found out how to border the whole image, not just a rectangle inside it.

Comment: I know how do it by using pixSetPixel, but that's kinda slow, plus I am thinking that there must be a function inside the lib. For now I will use my own function: 

`void SetBorder(PIX* img,BOX *b)
{
  for(int i=0; i< b->w;i++)
  {
   pixSetRGBPixel(img,b->x+i,b->y,255,255,255);
       pixSetRGBPixel(img,b->x+i,b->y+b->h,255,255,255);
  }
  for(int i=0; i< b->h;i++)
  {
   pixSetRGBPixel(img,b->x,b->y+i,255,255,255);
   pixSetRGBPixel(img,b->x+b->w,b->y+i,255,255,255);
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Your method works only for images depth of 3 bpp. Use the pixPaintBoxa or pixDrawBoxa method. See https://tpgit.github.io/Leptonica/boxfunc3_8c.html#a2dca217227f62a99f6003910420b47ba for more details. These methods work for any bpp.

However to use these functions, you have to build leptonica again using static makefiles. See http://www.leptonica.com/source/README.html#DEVELOP for more details.